# Excel using COUNTIFS Function to create a Punchcard

Tags: excel

In my data source I have a column that contains the Dates of occurrences and a Column that contains the Hour of the same occurrences.

With this, the goal is to obtain a punchcard plot (maybe the bubble chart will be the most appropriate)

The intermediate structure has the weekday(Sunday-Saturday) as rows (A2:A8), and the hours (8-22) as Columns (B1:P1), as each column must have the occurrence count for a week day in an hour.

With this said, I tried to use the COUNTIFS function, using the following approach, for the cell B2:

```
=COUNTIFS(WEEKDAY(RawData!T2:T9852;1);A2;HOUR(RawData!U2:U9852);B1)
```

However, Excel is not computing the value, finding a problem on the formula, having also tried using the Insert Formula Option.

Comment: use the following formulas in a blank cell in your RawData sheet and let use know the answers.  `=ISTEXT(T3)` and `=ISTEXT(U3)`.  Assuming that T3 and U3 contain some values.  One last question, is the first day of the week in you system Sunday or Monday or some other day of the week?

Comment: @ForwardEd Both of the text checks returned false. The additional parameter on the weekday (1) forces the first week-day to be Sunday. I believe that this might be a Syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place the following in B2

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY($T$2:$T$8,1)=WEEKDAY($A2,1))*(HOUR($U$2:$U$8)=HOUR(B$1)))
```

you will need to convert the `,` to match the `;` on your system

1. In your range A2:A8 enter a known date for monday such as 2017/08/20.  Then select A2:A8 and apply custom formatting for the number format and set it to ddd.  This will display the day of the week in text but keep the value in the cell a number.
2. Adjust the ranges to suit your data.
3. Copy the formula to fill in your table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the $ correction. However, when pressing CSE, the error message that I was experiencing persists.

Comment: hrmmm  I am away from computer again...I will be back in about 2 hours.   I will give you a work around for now but it will involve a helper column.

Comment: I revamped the formula and used some test data on it.